# Python 2.7: OOP error Geometry.def__init__(self,uid),AttributeError: type object 'Geometry' has no attribute 'def__init__'

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, inheritance

I am creating a base class `Geometry` with 1 attribute `id` = A unique ID for each `Geometry` object, an integer that starts at 0. Using a constructor (`__init__`) for when creating a new `Geometry` object. The constructor of the `Geometry` class should automatically assign the `ID` of the `Geometry` object.

I've created a subclass `Point` that inherits the `Geometry` class and contains the following attributes: `uid` (inherited from `Geometry`), `x` (The `x` coordinate of the `Point`) and y (The `y` coordinate of the `Point`).

I used `__init__` constructor to create new Point object having an `ID` inherited from the `Geometry` class as well as x and y coordinates. I used a string conversion method to return a string representation of the point.

My current code:

```
#Class Geometry
#attribute id
class Geometry(object):
    def __init__(self,uid=0):
        uid = 0
        self.uid = uid
        uid += 1 #not sure if this is neseccary. said uniqueId needs to start at 0, nothing about progressing


class Point(Geometry):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        Geometry.def__init__(self,uid)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return self.uid + self.x + self.y
```

Example output:

> p1 = Point(1.216, 3.4582)
>   Error: Geometry.def__init__(self,uid)
>   AttributeError: type object 'Geometry' has no attribute 'def__init__'

Any guidance is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `Geometry.def__init__(self,uid)  -> Geometry.__init__(uid)`

Comment: I am not sure why I am getting the error GoBrewers14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite clear, and even tells you where it is occurring. You are calling `Geometry.def__init__`, but Geometry does not have any such method, nor should it. I expect you mean `Geometry.__init__`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel Roseman. I am a programming newbie and completely missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself, where is the function, `def__init__`, located in your code? Look up what an AttributeError is, and reread your code carefully.